# What's with the tolerance for answers and comments that change the OP's spec or use-case?

Tags: discussion

This may sound general but it isn't. I frequently find respondents who second-guess the OP or even worse assert that the best/better/correct method lies outside the spec posted by the OP.

Here's a specific example.

*[Is there an “exists” function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)*

The OP asked a jQuery question. Not a JavaScript question, not a JavaScript-flavored question, but a jQuery question. Note the bandwidth given to user Magne (39 upvotes). A lively debate ensues in the comments on the post. This is only the first person to actually answer the question in this way.

If I work in a jQuery environment I may not have vanilla JavaScript accepted at all; it's also possible I may have asked a simple use-case question in pursuit of higher philosophical aims. I could call on a million different reasons why I might ask for a specific technology, context, or application in my question.

So why should I have to take my bandwidth to explain such things after saying "in jQuery" in my original question?

Whether it's a straight-up question or an artfully procured question, I don't believe either one expects or gains too much by suggesting that the methodology employed is wrong unless it is inherently wrong.

I do not feel it is appropriate for language-bashing to occur. Neither should it be silently tolerated for so many upvotes on a non-use-case answer as provided in my example.

OK, maybe I don't really want admins reviewing upvotes... but if there were more subtle moderation of such events in the community, it could continue to promote valuable digression and philosophical expansion- without providing tacit approval for second-guessing an OP which seems to be rampant here.

Opinionated programming and frameworks are one thing, and I definitely fall into this category of programmer more often than not... but this regular occurrence is one of my biggest pet peeves here on the site.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that answer, or any of the other upvoted answers there (Posted 5 years ago BTW)

Comment: Q: "How do I use a screw driver to hammer a nail?"  A: "Use a hammer".  This kind of Q+A had to be done in the early years of SO, thank heavens it is all taken care of.

Comment: Nice, another person ranting about people who donate their time free of charge to help others.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of things going on here. First, there is a long-running [meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/295232) on Stack Overflow about developers using jQuery for even the most simple JavaScript tasks. That might or might not have been an inspiration for this user to post a non-jQuery solution.

Second, the answers posted are not only for the OP, but *especially* aimed at future readers of the page. For them, it may be a cause of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676); they use jQuery and want to know if an element exists, so they type 'jQuery exists function' in Google, and they end up on this page. Some of those users might be perfectly happy with a non-jQuery solution, especially given the benefits mentioned.

A minor third point is that the answer actually has 50 upvotes and 11 downvotes, so there are definitely people who don't agree with the answer.

[image]

> Neither should it be silently tolerated for so many upvotes on a non-use-case answer as provided in my example.
>
> Ok maybe I don't really want admins reviewing upvotes...

If you see an upvoted answer which does not comply to Stack Overflow standards (e.g. because it is a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)), you can always *flag* the answer, and it will be reviewed. But, as Pekka 웃 and I explained, there is nothing wrong with this particular answer.

Comment: nice minor point. Good perspective.

Answer (score 1):

"Stack Overflow moderates itself as a very terse question and answer site. It’s not a discussion forum." (Steven K Hicks)

The OP seems to think that intelligent discussion of programming memes is the point of this site, so mistakenly apprises the answers here.

Yes, it's true. As a programmer of 36 years who is constantly pushing the envelope, I do care about the why's and the wherefore's of language, I am always opting to learn new language and rarely use SO to find mundane answers, even though I frequently find SO answers in top search results based on my seemingly constant research online.

I will adjust my expectations of this site and thank those who have answered my post.